# Fql mutliquery limit

Tags: facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I need to retrieve all Facebook counters of comments or share for each url of the site where I work. I wrote a batch who retrieves the counters by sending FQL multiqueries on the `link_stat` table. The number of URL in the site is approximately 400 000, so I have to do 400 000 requests... The batch will execute once a day.

I need to determine the number of requests in each FQL multiquery and the frequence of sending multiquery.
I have read there is a request limit who can throw the exception

> error =     {message = n request limit reached";type =
>   OAuthException;};"(#4) Application request limit
>   reached","type":"OAuthException"}}.

How can I determine this limit?

Comment: If there's 400,000 URLs and you're using multiquery, why do you need to make 400,000 requests? why not ask for multiple urls at once? should be able to cut the number of calls by 10x-20x?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry I express myself badly.
I want ask for multiple urls into multiquery so I don't have 400 000 request, I have 400 000 queries divided in multiqueries.
I think I can't send a single multiquery with 400 000 queries, the multiquery would be too big ?
I think I should divide this multiquery into smaller multiqueries.
But what is the maximum size of a multiquery, what is the maximum number of queries into a single multiquery ? My second question is How many multiqueries can I send in one day ?
I m afraid of a black listing...